# Asp.net 5 (MVC 6) web application - can not use email as user name

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a new MVC6 application and tried to register my first user and got the following error.

"*User name 'administrator@parkatstreet.com' is invalid, can only contain letters or digits.*"

Please note that I am working on VS 2015 installation ( Version 4.6.00081) and I have tried these steps in other versions of ASP.net eg: 2013, it is working without any problem.

To reproduce this issue, please create a new project in Vs 2015.

Step 1: Create a new Asp.net web application in VS 2015.

Step 2: Select Asp.net Preview templates, Web application

Step 3: Build

Step 4: Go to Account/Register

Step 5: enter any Email id and password, click register

Please let me know what I miss here?

Comment: What does your `UserValidator` config code look like?

Comment: It is a brand new application. I haven't changed any code, so not added any user validator.

Comment: If anyone else facing this problem? I think the latest ms build of VS2015 is buggy. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In asp.net beta7 the default template would require email/password for registration.

Try to install updated tooling from [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48738&fa43d42b-25b5-4a42-fe9b-1634f450f5ee=True) and create a new project.